# The New Apprentice

Tags: geometry

[image]

An apprentice went to a new building to measure the CHB wall area to be painted. He is equipped with Laser Distance Meter that measure the distance from that device to a wall (by means of reflected beam). The doors are of standard dimension while the ceilings are of same height. He started taking measurements 'inside' the building using the device. Unfortunately, the battery ran out after his 5th measurements and the area must be submitted to his boss soon. Nevertheless he used his acquired measurements to be able compute for the total CHB area.

Which measurements did he took? (pls. draw in above plan)

Comment: CHB (Concrete Hollow Block) wall are the white lines.

Comment: Does he know the ceiling height or does he have to acquire it from measurements?

Comment: You only need to know which 5 measurements he took

Comment: @Verence-No, that is one of the measurements. Right question.

Comment: Is glass simply invisible to the distance meter?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan- Yes refraction dont affect the reading

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [image]
>  The numbers show the measurements starting points. The fifth measurement is the ceiling. The Roman numbers mark the segments whose lengths (only sum of them, not the lengths themselves) are obtained after the measurement. I've put "splitting" marks on some walls for convenience so that segments visually go in pairs.
>  The final formula is (2*l1 + l2 + 2*l3 + 2*l4)*l5

Comment: Nicely drawn.  Also possibly (technically) need to subtract 6x(area of a door) in the final formula.

Comment: @DanRussell Of course.

Comment: @DanRussell Actually it's 10x(area of a door). ;)

Comment: @Sleafar Precisamundo.

Answer (score 2):

[EDITED to add:] Note that this is a *wrong answer*. I believe Verence's is right; in particular it uses the right cheeky trick to overcome what at first looks like an insuperable difficulty.

He measured

> the height of the ceiling (h); the distance from west of dining area to "middle" of cuisine (x1); the distance from west of cuisine to east of cuisine (x2); the distance from south of cuisine to north of reception (y1); the distance from south of exclusive to north of exclusive (y2).

Then

> the total length of east-west wall is $2(x_1+x_2)$ and the total length of north-south wall is $2(y_1+y_2)$ and so the total area of wall is $2h(x_1+x_2+y_1+y_2)$.

Comment: Does this depend on the office y dimension being a specific fraction of the exclusive y dimension? I can't see how the office is being counted

Comment: You missed some parts. The reception part to the west of the glass partition isn't covered by X measurement, and the office east wall isn't covered by Y measurement.

Comment: @Verence Damn, you're right.

Comment: (About the X measurement, that is. The office east wall is covered just fine, unless I'm still confused.)

Comment: @Angzuril Imagine a N/S line sweeping across the office. The number of E-W walls it meets is 2 until the line reaches the W of the cuisine, then 4 until the line reaches the "middle" of the cuisine, then 2 again. So the total length of E-W wall is twice the distance from west edge to middle of cuisine plus twice the distance from west of cuisine to east wall. Similarly for the walls with the other orientation.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan At the top of exclusive, there is an even number of N-S walls, and at the bottom there is an odd number (due to glass). I don't see how your y2 can account for the change in number of walls.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I was just preparing a diagram to clarify things and noticed that I had miscounted at one point. Just figuring out whether I can fix it without requiring physically impossible measurements...

Comment: ... Yeah, I can -- but y'know what?, it doesn't really contribute anything beyond Verence's answer, so I'll just leave this here being wrong. Apologies.

Comment: The infallible and prodigious GarethBot makes a pre-programmed mistake designed to convince the rest of us that it is fallible and not a bot at all. ;)